# double[] -> double[,]

Tags: c#

Just curious is there a quicker/neater way to achieve this:

```
double[] source = ... // some initialisation

var target = new double[1, source.Length];
for (var c = 0; c < source.Length; c++)
{
    target[0, c] = source[c];
}
```

Comment: Is `alphas` guaranteed to be an array of same length as source ?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why do you create a two-dimentional array with only one row?

Comment: If you now how target is layout in memory I guess you could use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx but that for sure is not portable and brittle...

Comment: sorry there was a mistake (alpha -> source). I have to do this for some pinvoke stuff ...

Comment: Still not clear. If all you need is initializing a two dimentional array with some value, my answer solves it. But I think you should provide more information about your exact problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialiaze the array like this:

```
double[,] target = { { /* your list of values */ } };
```

Then you have a two dimentional array with only one row.

Comment: I am guessing he probably gets the first array passed from somewhere else, so he can't use an array initializer. At least that how I read the question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are mentioning this is for P/Invoke, BlockCopy is probably reasonable to use:

```
double[] source = new double [] {1,2,3,4,7,8,9,0};// some initialisation
double[,] target = new double[1, source.Length];

Buffer.BlockCopy(source, 0, target, 0, source.Length * sizeof(double));
```

Comment: Sounds interesting. What is the advantage over: double[,] target = { { /* your list of values */ } };? Thanks.

Comment: @csetzkorn Isn't converting from `double[]` to `double[,]` the point of your question? So if he'd initialize `double[,]` directly it wouldn't answer your question anymore.

Comment: @csetzkorn, if you are in a position where you can hardcode the values into an initializer, by all means, do that, it's simpler. But that approach can't be used if you cannot express the array by means of compile time constants.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I am still allowed to comment aren't I? If necessary, I would post another question. I do not think that your comment is very helpful.